# How can I prove I am closely related to my sponsor?

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, applications

I am going to apply for a uk visit visa to visit my Aunt and for tourism. My Aunt will be my sponsor, and on my application I have to show the visa officer that my Aunt and I have a strong close relationship.

Would you help me with what I should show the visa officer to prove that my Aunt and I are closely related?

Comment: Birth certificates of the relevant relatives? Details of regular contact between you eg phone calls, emails, visits by your aunt to your family?